# counting queryset returns 'list' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a model with a manytomany column. I want to limit the number of groups a user can submit.

Here is what I'm doing

```
        group_name = [g.id for g in form.cleaned_data['groups']]
        gr=group_name.id.count()
        if gr>3:
            raise forms.ValidationError("you can only add 3 groups")
        return group_name
```

the error is:

```
 Exception Value: 'list' object has no attribute 'id'
```

I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a `list` object, so standard `list` operations work.

```
group_name_ids = [g.id for g in form.cleaned_data['groups']]
group_id_count = len(group_name_ids)
```

It seems that `"groups"` here is a list of model objects, so you could get the count via:

```
group_count = len(form.cleaned_data["groups"])
```

However, since your returning the resulting built `group_name_ids` list, you might as well just get the `len()` of that.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't explore len much because [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) said:
"Note: Don't use len() on QuerySets if all you want to do is determine the number of records in the set". But with such a small set, it doesn't matter. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, for querysets you should use .count(), but here your referencing the form's cleaned_data dictionary and making a list of the ids.

Answer (score 0):

`group_name` is a list, and `group_name.id` cannot be resolved :)

Comment: Thanks for the response Yevgen. How can I make it countable? Or, is there a way to count the cleaned_data?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that familiar with Django. What are you trying to  do? Maybe len(group_name) does what you want?

Comment: That was the solution, but monkut got there first.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> nk=['city1','city2','city1','city3','city1']
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> mycount=Counter()
>>> for word in nk:
...     mycount[word]+=1
...     
>>> mycount['city1']
3
>>>
```

refer python documentaion http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html